# While condition always false but code still runs!? Java magic?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] wordsToAdd = {"cat", "dog", "horse", "zebra"};

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            words.add(wordsToAdd[i]);

        }
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newWord = keyboard.next();

        int x = 0;
        while (newWord.compareToIgnoreCase(words.get(x)) > 0 && 
        x < words.size()) {
        x++;
        }
        words.add(x, newWord);


        for (String string : words) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

the following code makes sense as long as the word entered by user is at least greater than the first word in the arraylist("cat").

however when i enter "ant" it still works and puts "ant" at index 0.
as far as i can see when the word entered provides a negative int, in the case of ant vs cat it's -2. how does it exit the loop and how does it put ant at index 0?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: X starts at zero. If the loop isn't entered, it stays there, and is added at the beginning.

Comment: There is nothing called "java magic". Java is a programming language, and abides by strict rules. If there was "java magic" then we would never be able to ensure how a program would work, which could lead to disasters in production.

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of your program, but "ant" doesn't satisfy the first condition. `compareToIgnoreCase()` returns a number less than 0 if the first string is lexicographically less than the other string. As "ant" is less than "cat", this will violate the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is never entered, so the next line after the loop is executed immediately. If we cut the while loop from your program, the following remains:

```java
int x = 0;
words.add(x, newWord);
```

Thus the word is added to the beginning of the list.

> the following code makes sense as long as the word entered by user is at least greater than the first word in the arraylist("cat").

No, `compareToIgnoreCase` compares string *contents*, ignoring case, and does not compare *length*. If you want to order to words by length, you need to compare their length, not what letters they contain.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don’t know how I forgot that while loops are only executed when the conditions are met. 
Please forgive a noob and thank you all for input.